# Function to map Maybes to a monad

Tags: haskell, monads, standard-library

I often use expressions of the form `maybe (return ()) someFunc someMaybe`.

Searching for a function `Monad m => (a -> m ()) -> Maybe a -> m ()` on hoogle doesn't yield a specific result. Isn't there any library function for this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `mapM_` or `forM_` from [Data.Foldable](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Foldable.html) for this. See also [the recent discussion on the librariers mailing list](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2011-November/017253.html).